# Accessing state in child class

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have a button on a webpage that displays a popup div. The popup also has a close button on it that hides it. What is the proper way to do this in reactjs? My thinking is to have a state on the button that toggles the visibility of the popup, while the popup modifies it.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {visible: false};
    },
    buttonOnClick: function() {
        if(this.state.visible == true)
            this.setState({visible: false});
        else
            this.setState({visible: true});
    },
    render: function() {
        var elem;
        if(this.state.visible)
            elem = <Popup/>
        else
            elem = "";
        ...
        {elem}
    }
}

var Popup = React.createClass({
    closeButtonOnClick: function() {
        this.setState({visible: false});   //this.state is null!
    }
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

However, I can't access the state from the child class and passing it as a prop doesn't seem to work either (pass by value, not reference). How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of accessing state on the parent component directly, just pass a callback to `<Popup>` like `onClose` which the `<Parent>` handles by setting `setState({visible: false})`:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {visible: false};
    },
    buttonOnClick: function() {
        if(this.state.visible == true)
            this.setState({visible: false});
        else
            this.setState({visible: true});
    },
    handlePopupClose: function() {
        this.setState({visible: false});
    },
    render: function() {
        var elem;
        if(this.state.visible)
            elem = <Popup onClose={this.handlePopupClose}/>
        else
            elem = "";
        ...
        {elem}
    }
}

var Popup = React.createClass({
    closeButtonOnClick: function() {
        this.props.onClose();
    }
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: took the words out of my mouth :)

Comment: ahh I see, you pass a callback. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question: If my DOM looks like
`body 
  >popup-container
  >div
  >>div2
  >>>div3
  >>>>div4
`
And I want to control popup visibility from div4 or other divs, do I need to pass a callback all the way down and to each element that will generate a popup?

Comment: Well the DOM matters less so than the component hierarchy, but the general answer to your question is: yes, you need to explicitly pass the callback through all component props, OR you can use something like Flux or Redux to manage global app state.